# Is it possible to use starlette framwork to interact with elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, starlette

I am facing difficulty in accessing the elasticsearch index using starlette framework

My main.py is

```
from urllib.request import Request
from webbrowser import get
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.routing import Route
import time
import warnings   
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "item_name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "price": {
                "type": "float"
            }
        }
    }
}

index_name = "students"
# Password for the 'elastic' user generated by Elasticsearch
ELASTIC_PASSWORD = "xxxxx"

query = {"query": {"bool": {"must": {"term": {"item_name": "apple"}}}}}


def connection():
    url = "https://localhost:9200"        
    es = Elasticsearch(url,
                       ca_certs="xxx",
                       basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD))
    return es


def create_index():
    es = connection()
    index_name = "students"
    print("hello")
    try:
        index_exists = es.indices.exists(index=index_name)
        if not index_exists:
            es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=mapping)
            print("Index created successfully!")

    except Exception as err:
        print("Elasticsearch error:", err)


def home(request: Request):
    return True



routes = [Route("/", endpoint=home, methods=[])]          

          
app = Starlette(
    routes=routes
)


@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():    
    create_index()
```

while running this i am getting 500 internal server error

My questions are:

1. how to create the route path for elastic search
2. if it possible to create then in which port i can see the output (default port of elasticsearch or starlette)

kindly share some examples

Comment: what do you want to get if you call your `/` endpoint (of your webserver)

Comment: did you try to add logs before/between/after the Elasticsearch related lines?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can access the elastic db with the normal python commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).